# How to remove extra slash of optional parameter on first level in URL?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to make first parameter optional for login state and it works with below .state definition

```
$stateProvider
.state("login", {
          url: '/:team/login/',
          templateUrl: 'app/user/login.html',
          controller: 'LoginController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          data: {
              requiresAuth: false,
              pageTitle: 'Login'
          }
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
```

now my issue comes up when there is no team name than there comes two forward slash `//` ;

*`http://localhost:3000/#//login/`*

how to remove this extra forwardslash `/` so that `http://localhost:3000/#/login/` started working as well

**my trials**

1. `url: '[/:team]/login/' and url: '/[:team/]login/'`

   But than url being encoded and turns into `http://localhost:3000/#/%5B/%5Dlogin/`
2. `$urlRouterProvider.when('//login', '/login');`

   but not working
3. added params condition

   ```
     params: { 
           team: {squash: true, value: null }
     }
   ```

but this even stops my previous working urls as well

Do I need to create one more state or something which can be done to make it working. Kindly help

Comment: what will be the value of team **that you want to show in url** 
(eg.:http://localhost:3000/#/21/login/ )

Comment: that's everything fine, whatever team name i write it comes fine. I just want url to work it without team also but it comes with extra `/`

Comment: can i see your `ui-sref` call to login or `$state.go()` call to login code lines?

Comment: here is `<a ui-sref="login" href="#" >
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login
                    </a>`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change some codes. There are two ways possible. Two work with both (team present and team absent), you can't simply use ui-sref(and please don't use `href` along with `ui-sref`). So here I'm calling a function on clicking on `login` button

**One way**

HTML :

```
<a ng-click="goLogin(team.name)"> <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login </a>  
<!-- expecting you are passing team name(you can change it) -->
```

JS:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("login", {
      url: ':team/login/',
      templateUrl: 'app/user/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      data: {
          requiresAuth: false,
          pageTitle: 'Login'
      }
 });

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
```

In your controller.

```
 $scope.goLogin = function(team_name){
  if(team_name){
    team_name = '/'+ team_name    // will add a slash only if team_name is present
  }
  else{
   team_name = ''
  }
  $state.go({'team': team_name})
}
```

If not working, inject `$sate` into your controller as

```
.controller('myCtrl', ['$state', 'other_depend'], function($state, other_depend){
 ......
})
```

Comment: this gives error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined** from angular.ui.router.js file  `function isRelative(stateName) {
    return stateName.indexOf(".") === 0 || stateName.indexOf("^") === 0;
  }`

Comment: and we can not pass team.name manually in `goLogin()` for each team